# Drag & drop on launcher icon does not raise focus

Tags: 11.04, compiz

I drag file over launcher icon (running program) after which program raises and I drop the file.

Problem I have here is that although program loads the file, it does not gain focus, so I have to alt-tab to it, to gain focus and use program's actions. This ruins drag&drop purpose for me, as if I have to alt-tab then I could first alt-tab and then drag&drop, instead dragging to launcher, waiting application to raise and dropping the file, and then yet alt-tab.

I guess it's one of those Compiz issues, but maybe someone has a tip which Compiz setting can solve this problem, if possible?

Comment: Have you tried this with 11.10 to confirm that it still occurs? (You can use a Live CD/USB for that)

Comment: No, I haven't. Maybe someone running 11.10 can confirm

Comment: I've confirmed that it's only a problem in 11.04.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in 11.04. I tested in 11.10, and while the program window is not raised, the file is transferred to the application and it is raised afterwards (at least Firefox, which I tested, was raised).

Comment: Thanks for confirming Roland. Here is one more example in addition: I open Gedit and minimize it, then I drag file from Nautilus to Gedit icon - Gedit raises and I drop the file in it. However Gedit does not have focus, and I can't use keyboard or menu etc unless I alt-tab to it. If Gedit wasn't minimized then (I guess by default Compiz setting) Gedit window is bring to front and zoomed out, and I can drop file and Gedit has focus. So issue is only when application is minimized.

Comment: Moreover as Gedit has .desktop file with defined mime type associations, there seems to be another possibility if application is minimized - just drop the file on launcher icon, without hovering over it to be raised - in that case focus is also gained.

Comment: I just thought there is some Compiz setting buried in CCSM that can tweak this out

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Unity is not designed to do that. I think you would have to make a suggestion the ayatan mailing list.

Comment: Hm, that would be strange. Why does application raise itself when I drag file over it launcher icon?

Comment: @zetah: most applications will be raised once you drag something to them, and also what normally happens in most window managers is when you drag something to a window, the window is highlighted. I think your specific requirement of raising "focus" is what is leading to the confusion.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment. I'm not sure if you understand mine also. I can't see a reason why minimized application should raise from minimized state to unfocused restored state if I hover over it launcher icon with dragged file. If d&d feature I'm explaining is not supported then hovering over some launcher icon with dragged file, should have no effect. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @zetah: I'm lost now lol (as in, I can't explain further). I think you are missing something - and it is also a bit of a shortcoming in Unity at the same time.

Comment: OK, let it be :)